# Python [WinError 32] with shutil.move(source, destination) during the move (writes most of the file, but not all)

Tags: python, csv, shutil

I'm trying to add a reference to an image file to a downloaded csv filled with product names and skus.

I downloaded a csv file with 1055 lines (products), I have 1,635 gallery images that should be tied to those products. So after the loop I should have a temp csv file with 1,635 lines. Where products with multiple images are listed as duplicates.

```
base_csv = 'products_gallery.csv'
temp_csv = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)

gallery_path = 'path_to_images/compressed_gallery'
gallery_imgs = os.listdir(gallery_path)

fields = ['name','sku','product_id','gallery_image']

#update all rows to contain the images.
with open(base_csv, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields, delimiter='\t') #read downloaded csv file
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_csv, fieldnames=fields, delimiter='\t') #write to temp csv file
    for row in reader:
        for img_name in gallery_imgs: #loop through local images and match product names
            if row['name'] in img_name:
                row['gallery_image'] = img_name
                writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                continue

time.sleep(10) #doesn't help

shutil.move(temp_csv.name, base_csv)
```

The code crashes on the last line above with

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
> because it is being used by another process:
> 'C:\path_to_user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgu67y173'

Yet somehow it manages to write/update my main csv file to 1,569 lines, missing only the last 39 products. The temp csv file that's created has all 1,635 lines. I don't know why this would work partially instead of not at all. I've used this exact code before to modify other csv files that I've created without any issues.

I've tried:
clearing out python processes from the Task Manager
Rebooting to clear out processes
adding time.sleep(10) before the shutil.move() just in case it needs time to close the file or something

Answer (score 0):

It seems I forgot to include the temp file with my open command and therefore the temp file wasn't being closed properly.

```
with open(base_csv, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile, temp_csv:
```

Changing this line here resolved the issue.